# Using inline-block adds space below the elements in dompdf

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

When there are two or more elements with `display:inline-block`, those elements appear to have a margin below after being rendered as a pdf:

```
<div style="background-color:pink;">
    <div style="background-color:red;float:left;width:25%;">Hello</div>
    <div style="background-color:orange;float:left;width:25%;">Hello</div>
    <div style="background-color:yellow;float:left;width:25%;">Hello</div>
    <div style="background-color:green;float:left;width:25%;position:relative;">
        <div style="background-color:red;display:inline-block;width:25%;">Hello</div><!--
        --><div style="background-color:orange;display:inline-block;width:25%;">Hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: multiple inline-block elements]

But when there is only one, it display fine:

```
<div style="background-color:pink;">
    <div style="background-color:red;float:left;width:25%;">Hello</div>
    <div style="background-color:orange;float:left;width:25%;">Hello</div>
    <div style="background-color:yellow;float:left;width:25%;">Hello</div>
    <div style="background-color:green;float:left;width:25%;position:relative;">
        <div style="background-color:red;display:inline-block;width:25%;">Hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: single inline-block element]

Already tried using `clear:both` on a sibling element and as a wrapper of the `inline-block` elements, but that only caused it to go below the green div

Also already tried using `float:left`, just like its parent, but using it caused the elements to just overlap

Is/are there any other way to make the children of a floated element to align horizontally?

Comment: if you add some css to remove the margin (eg. `margin: 0;`) what happen ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `inline-block` has a default style of `vertical-align: baseline` which can lead to positioning issues. Add `vertical-align: top` or `vertical-align: bottom` to all your `inline-blocks` to fix this.